# Cómo evitar el error del CATIA.FileSelectionBox() sin setear "regserver option" como administrador?

Tags: vba, users-roles

El siguiente código funcionamuy bien con permisos de administrador de CATIA. Sinembargo no funciona al correr la macro como usuario.

```
Sub CATMain()
On Error Resume Next
Dim strpath As String

strpath = CATIA.FileSelectionBox("Select file", "*.xlsx", 
CatFileSelectionModeOpen)

End Sub
```

Estimo que CATIA.FileSelectionBox() funciona bien usando CATScript por lo que estaba pensando en ejecutar una subrutina CATScript usando Application.ExecuteScript(). Al hacerlo aparece un nuevo error "Function or interface marked as restricted...".
Alguien tiene una solucion alternativa a este problema? Desde ya agadezco la colaboracion!

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate it.

Comment: Ok, mejor aún! Gracias! Si no consigo respuestas, puedo volver a publicar en inglés?

Comment: si, pero en el sitio en ingles.. aca solo en español...

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta! Si bien no es la ideal ya que al codigo no se le pueden agragar filtros para distintos tipos de archivos (ej: *.CATPart, *.CATProduct, etc), funciona muy bien para seleccionar archivos con una macro VBA dentro de CATIA.

```
Function SelectFile( )
' File Browser via HTA
' Author:   Rudi Degrande, modifications by Denis St-Pierre and Rob van der 
Woude
' Features: Works in Windows Vista and up (Should also work in XP).
'           Fairly fast.
'           All native code/controls (No 3rd party DLL/ XP DLL).
' Caveats:  Cannot define default starting folder.
'           Uses last folder used with MSHTA.EXE stored in Binary in 
[HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32].
'           Dialog title says "Choose file to upload".
' Source:   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-
US/a3b358e8-15ae-4ba3-bca5-ec349df65ef6/windows7-vbscript-open-file-dialog-
box-fakepath?forum=ITCG

Dim objExec, strMSHTA, wshShell

SelectFile = ""

' For use in HTAs as well as "plain" VBScript:
strMSHTA = "mshta.exe ""about:" & "<" & "input type=file id=FILE>" _
     & "<" & "script>FILE.click();new 
ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" _
     & 
".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);" & "<" & 
"/script>"""
' For use in "plain" VBScript only:
' strMSHTA = "mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE>" _
'          & "<script>FILE.click();new 
ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" _
'          & 
".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);
</script>"""

Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set objExec = wshShell.Exec( strMSHTA )

SelectFile = objExec.StdOut.ReadLine( )

Set objExec = Nothing
Set wshShell = Nothing
End Function
```

Les agradezco por permitirme postear mi pregunta y espero que esta respuesta le sirva a alguien en el futuro. Saludos!